# const array index pointer conversion from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have been trying to convert the following c++ code to c# for a number of days. Indexing an array by reference, with the reference being determined by the result of a calculation.

```
pData[data_id] ^= ((const uint8_t *)ValueTable)[tbl_id & 0x3FF];
```

The evaluation of the expression on the right hand side is the area I am struggling with.

When I try to do this in c# I am getting the result as an array value and not it's index.

When I try to use it as an index, The result of the index calculation (0x309) is outside of the bounds of the fixed array size (256x UInt32 values) so every time I feel I am getting close to this I get an out of bounds exception in c#.... This does not appear to be an issue in c++?

Apologies if this is obvious to you all, my experience of c++ and c# is limited. If anyone is able to point me in a direction here that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without C# code it's hard to be sure, but I think your problem is that you are indexing 4 byte values (`UInt32`) instead of single byte values (`uint8_t`).

Comment: Please add some c# code, so we can help

Comment: Create an array of 0x400 bytes.  byte[] pData = new byte[0x400].  If you are calling c++ you must put the array in unmanaged memory.  So using Marshal.Alloc() will return a pointer of size needed.  If you are returning the value from c++ then you must copy unmanaged object to managed memory using Marshal.PtrToStructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the C# and what the values actually are. `tbl_id & 0x3FF == 0x309` is certainly possible, as all the bits in `0x309` are also set in `0x3FF`.

- If you are using `& 0x3FF`, then I would expect `ValueTable` to have `0x3FF + 1` elements (1024).
- If `ValueTable` only really should have 256 elements and it should wrap around, then use `& 0xFF` (note that using `%` is generally safer for wrapping if the low bits may not be set, say if you have 100 elements).
- If `ValueTable` is meant to be 1024 bytes (`uint8_t`), then use `byte[1024]` in C# rather than 256 32bit integers.
- If `ValueTable` is 256 32bit integers, but you want to access a byte here, then changing it to `byte[]` is the most straightforward, else take the integer index (`index / 4`), then get the relevant byte from that integer (possibly `i = tbl_id & 0x3FF; BitConverter.GetBytes(table[i / 4])[i % 4]`;)

Comment: Many thanks Fire Lancer. I converted the 256 elements into an array of 1024x byte values using ````BitConverter.GetBytes```` and referenced the result of the calculation as the array index.